# using multiple command interpreters in a linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell, expect

I want to use a single shell script to perform a bunch of commands. Some of these commands include: scp, cd, tar, date, expect, spawn.

When I declare #!/bin/sh or #!/bin/bash none of the expect commands work- this is understandable. When I declare #!/usr/bin/expect -f then cd, tar, date don't work- I suppose this is to be expected (no pun) as well.

Is it possible to use all these commands using a single interpreter or can I declare another along the way? I dove into sub shells but that didn't work out.

Comment: I recommend writing one language per source file. Put your expect code  into an expect fail and call that from within your Bourne or Bash Script. You can have no more than one [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line.

Answer (score 3):

You can feed commands to `expect` via a shell here-doc:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# shell code....
expect <<EOS
# expect code...
EOS
# back to shell code...
```

Comment: +1. You just have to be careful with the quoting, to make sure that bash doesn't try to expand your expect variables. Quoting the heredoc delimiter goes a long way to accomplising this: `expect << 'EOS'` -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

Comment: Thank you, all of you. I have plenty of options now.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you run under expect, you have [all the commands of Tcl](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.5/tcl/tcl_contents.htm) available and therefore:

- "cd" will work because it's built-in
- "date" is not needed because you can use the Tcl clock command, eg. `clock format [clock seconds]`
- "tar" and other external commands can be run with exec, eg. `exec tar cf stuff.tar file1 file2 file3`

The data and control constructs are different from sh or bash, but more powerful once you get used to them.